# Setting Proxy when doing web scraping with BeautifulSoup and Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, proxy

Im trying to scrape one website, and I wanted to add some proxies. I have read the documentation on stackoverflow, and on other sites and I saw this solution:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

proxies = {
            "https": "178.155.104.84:59071",
            "http": "178.155.104.84:59071"
            }

r = requests.get("https://httpbin.org/ip")
print(r.json()) # this should return my IP address
r = requests.get("https://httpbin.org/ip", proxies = proxies)
print(r.json())  # this should return other IP address / to change IP address
```

But the problem is that I get this error:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 420, in __init__
    raise ProxySchemeUnknown(proxy.scheme)
urllib3.exceptions.ProxySchemeUnknown: Not supported proxy scheme None
```

I have tried with other proxies, but the error is the same. I found proxies from this website: https://free-proxy-list.net/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide scheme for Your proxies - add http/https:

```
proxies = {
    "https": "http://178.155.104.84:59071",
    "http": "http://178.155.104.84:59071"
}
```